# JavaScript- how to create dynamically multiple divs with inputs field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-input, textinput

I have to create 3 input text boxes for getting user input about names and email addresses.
I have to create it dynamically, ***i.e.*** as the user clicks on the email input field a new line of all the three element supposed to be created.
This is the code for one line with the 3 inputs:

```
<div class='row' id="inputcontainer">
        <div class="form-group clearfix" >
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="form-text-field first-name">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName10" class="signup-input" name="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-text-field last-name">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastName0" class="signup-input" name="" placeholder="optional">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-text-field email">
                    <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input text-value " name="email[0]"  placeholder="e.g. example@url.com"/>
                    <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to create it dynamically ?

I'm using the following code for cloning and it's clone it several times instead 1

```
maxIndex = 0;
$('form').on('input','.email',function(){

    $(this).parent().find('.common-sprite').removeClass('disNone');
    var lastmail = $(this);                                                                                  if(($(this).val().length > 0)&&(lastmail.data('index') == maxIndex)) {
        var count = $('.row.inputcontainer').length;
        console.log(count);
        maxIndex++;
        var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
        clone.find('.firstName[id=firstName'+(maxIndex-1)+']').attr('id', 'firstName' + maxIndex).attr('name', 'first[' + maxIndex +']').addClass('signup-input firstName').val('');
        clone.find('.lastName[id=lastName'+(maxIndex-1)+']').attr('id', 'lastName' + maxIndex).attr('name', 'last[' + maxIndex +']').addClass('signup-input lastName').val('');
        clone.find('.email[id=inputMail'+(maxIndex-1)+']').attr('id', 'inputMail' + maxIndex).attr('name', 'email[' + maxIndex +']').data('index', maxIndex).addClass('signup-input text-value email').val('');
        $('.inputcontainer').append(clone);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this? i used `.blur()` to trigger the dynamic adding so that if you type something in the email input and you click outside of it, then the next 3 lines of information will show up.  i also added some classes to help jquery find elements faster and more reliably.  i used `clone()` to recreate the same structure of the 3 lines every time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.email').on('blur', function() {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            var count = $('.row').length;
            console.log(count);
            var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
            clone.find('.firstName').attr('id', 'firstName' + count).val('');
            clone.find('.lastName').attr('id', 'lastName' + count).val('');
            clone.find('.email').attr('id', 'inputMail' + count).val('');
            $('body').append(clone);
        }         
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row inputcontainer' id="template">
    <div class="form-group clearfix" >
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-text-field first-name">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName0" class="signup-input firstName" name="" placeholder=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-text-field last-name">
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName0" class="signup-input lastName" name="" placeholder="optional"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-text-field email">
                <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input text-value email" name="email[0]"  placeholder="e.g. example@url.com"/>
                    <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: The problem that they have to be with the same classes of the one I created at first

Comment: @saritrotshild, yes, is that something you dont want? and why? id's have to be unique, but classes dont have to be. i changed the id's of the inputs so that they are unique...if you want the whole row to be unique, you can implement the same count to the row id.

Comment: @ndubitablee- I'm using the following code for cloning and it's clone it several times instead 1:

Comment: @saritrotshild i dont understand what you desire that makes my answer not sufficient in helping you with the issue of dynamic duplication...

Answer (score 1):

Is this something similar to what you would like?

```js
$(document).on("blur",".add",function()
{   
    $("#inputcontainer").append("<br />");
    $("#inputcontainer").append("First Name <input type='text' class='signup-input' name='' placeholder='' /><br />");
    $("#inputcontainer").append("last Name <input type='text' class='signup-input' name='' placeholder='optional' /><br />");
    $("#inputcontainer").append("Email Address <input type='text' data-index='0' class='signup-input text-value add' name='email[0]'  placeholder='e.g. example@url.com' /><br />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row' id="inputcontainer">
        <div class="form-group clearfix t" >
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="form-text-field first-name">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName10" class="signup-input" name="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-text-field last-name">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastName0" class="signup-input" name="" placeholder="optional">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-text-field email">
                    <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input text-value add" name="email[0]"  placeholder="e.g. example@url.com"/>
                    <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Type into the email textbox then leave to create the new textboxes.

Comment: Updated, it includes a form dynamically. Im working on the css now to tidy it up a bit.

Comment: @saritrotshild have a look now.

Comment: @Kylet- I thing you didn't understand the question. All the 3 input have to be in the same line. If the user click on the email field a whole new line with the 3 inputs has to be created

Comment: You shouldn't use the same ID more than once, an ID is used to target a specific element (One of).

Comment: @NewToJS I agree, i overlooked that while copying the OP's markup into JQuery.